# Can't execute an INSERT statement in a Python script via MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm trying to execute a basic `INSERT` statement on a MySQL table from a Python script using MySQLdb. My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `testfield` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Running this query from the MySQL command line works fine:

```
INSERT INTO `testtable` (`id`, `testfield`) VALUES (NULL, 'testvalue');
```

But when I try to execute the query from a Python script, no rows get inserted. Here's my code:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=db_host, port=db_port, user=db_user, passwd=db_password, db=db_database)
cursor = conn.cursor ()
cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO `testtable` (`id`, `testfield`) VALUES (NULL, 'testvalue')")
print "Number of rows inserted: %d" % cursor.rowcount
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Oddly, this will print "Number of rows inserted: 1." I can also confirm that this query increments the ID field, because when I add another row via the command line, the value of its ID is the same as if the Python script had successfully inserted its rows. However, running a `SELECT` query returns none of the rows from the script.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You either need to set `conn.autocommit()`, or you need to do `conn.commit()` - see [the FAQ](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#id3)

Comment: where I have to put `conn.autocommit()`? @JoeMornin @Henry

Answer (score 6):

you need to commit:

```
conn.commit()
```

[**`http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#my-data-disappeared-or-won-t-go-away`**](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#my-data-disappeared-or-won-t-go-away)

Comment: Thanks! I have been hunting all over looking for a fix and this was it.