# Python MySQLdb, simple chatroom/guestbook app

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I've browsed some of the other questions about MySQL and Python on SO. There are a few things eluding me, because I'm pretty new to Python.

First, I'm trying to get a simple guestbook app to work. It takes posted variables and puts them into a MySQL database.  Take a look:

```
con = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",
        user = "Chat",
        passwd = "myPass",
        db = "Chatserver")
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO guestbook (name,message) VALUES(%s,%s)",(name,greeting))
```

Ok, so some of the tutorials and answers on SO have many Quotation marks surrounding the SQL query, and I don't know why that is.  I've tried it with 1 quote, I've tried it with 3 quotes, and it just never works. There are no exception callbacks and the code seems to run, but no records are ever entered into the database.

So my two questions are, how many quotation marks do I need when encapsulating the Queries, and why doesn't my script add anything to the database but not report any errors?

Comment: You can use either one or three quotes to construct a python string. It's simply a matter of what syntax you prefer. As for the lack of an error message, I don't know!

Comment: I answered my own question after more research, I needed a con.commit() line to perform the query, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this answer [Can't execute an INSERT statement in a Python script via MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931771/cant-execute-an-insert-statement-in-a-python-script-via-mysqldb) helped me figure it out.

You have to add this at the end of your query.

```
cursor.execute(...)
con.commit()  //this is what makes it actually do the execution?
```